# Creating sub dataframes from a main one using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I wanna create sub dataframes from a main one 
My main dataframe will look more or less like this one [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMcgi.png)
I wanna be able to have as a sub-dataframe like the following :

[first sub dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQgvs.png)
[second sub dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMpzD.png)

and all the rest for example in an another frame. My goal is to transform correctly my big dataframe into sub dataframe.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks :-)

Comment: [Please don't post images of code (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: it wasn't really code but a view of a dataframe using pycharm. I thought it'd be more comprehensible to share a picture :-)

Comment: And thank you for your advice

Answer (score 0):

You can take a rectangular section with numeric indices like this:

```
df.iloc[4:8, 0:8] # four rows, eight columns
```

Or you can use `loc` with column and row labels (but your data seem to be numerically labeled).

Comment: the thing is I don't always have indexes which makes my problem a bit harder :/

Comment: @ImRi: OK, then you'll need to search in the data to find the indexes, right?  Do you have a remaining question?